# How to separate the generated code for an interface in Netbeans into different classes?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm developping an interface with Netbeans and I wanted to separate the creation of the GUI in three different classes. The reason why I'm doing this is that the project is following the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) model, and it would be more practical to create 3 models/views in this case (it's not just up to me).

I'm using the Design tool to develop it, using the GridBagLayout.  Also, the code is already generated (I had already finished the interface, then later the idea of dividing it appeared). In the interface, I have 3 tabs - the idea would be to create one tab in each class, but I could not find any examples or questions involving this while searching. Is it possible, and if yes, how to do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could create three JPanel classes with netbeans (each with their own generated code), one for each tab.

Then in the main frame/dialog/whatever, you insert the tabbedpane and add the three panels to it manually in the creation code.

If you want to split the code you already have, that's a bit more difficult. However, you can split it outside of netbeans (since then parts of the code won't be protected). I think it might be difficult for netbeans to load the corresponding files correctly (= in a way you can still work on them in the included editor. You will always be able to simply open them in netbeans) though.

Netbeans creates these .form files to work with the layout. So you'd have to look into how they are created.

Anyway, the easier solution would probably be to just plan stuff like that ahead of time or even recreate the tabs now instead of cutting the main thing apart.